# Flip all cards when clicking a button using flip_card flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

**Solved see the answers**

I am using flip card package to make flip cards.

I have many cards in the same page and I want to flip them all when I press a button.

I used the example in the documentation :

```dart
GlobalKey<FlipCardState> cardKey = GlobalKey<FlipCardState>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FlipCard(
    key: cardKey,
    flipOnTouch: false,
    front: Container(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => cardKey.currentState.toggleCard(),
        child: Text('Toggle'),
      ),
    ),
    back: Container(
      child: Text('Back'),
    ),
  );
}
```

but I get error `Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.` or `Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey` 

So what I can do to solve this problem ?

Comment: Why do you need a global key? I mean, are you doing anything with it at all?

Comment: No, I don't do anything with it but I used this method because I found it in the documentation : https://pub.dev/packages/flip_card 
Is there another method to flip all cards ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem with making a map of global keys

`var cardKeys = Map<int, GlobalKey<FlipCardState>>();`

and in the `ListView.builder` in `itemBuilder` I added

```
cardKeys.putIfAbsent(index, () => GlobalKey<FlipCardState>());
GlobalKey<FlipCardState> thisCard = cardKeys[index];
```

and in the `FlipCard` I added `key: thisCard`

Then I make a simple for loop in the button onPressed function

```
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                    cardKeys[i].currentState.toggleCard();
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Toggle'),
              ),
```

Thanks to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58415110/14833186)